# TypeError: hbs is not a function error ,while running the node.js express project I got this type of error in my app.js code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, express-handlebars

TypeError: hbs is not a function
at Object. (D:\Brototype\Web Development Challenge-2\shopping-cart\app.js:17:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
at Object. (D:\Brototype\Web Development Challenge-2\shopping-cart\bin\www:7:11)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)

Node.js v18.18.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
-------------------------------------[This is my app.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uce0w.png)                                                                                      Why showing this error while i already installed express-handlebars and connect engin in app.js

I try to run my code in terminal but It shoing error.
I need to run my server and check output on browser

Comment: Please [post your code instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/21972629) See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of handlebars is not correct. You need to call the `hbs.engine` function instead like so:

```js
app.engine("hbs", hbs.engine({
   extname: "hbs",
   defaultLayout: "layout",
   //...
}));
```